# how to have next line exporting csv file in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to give next line in row value if I have multiple value in one row and show in exporting `csv file` .

I want add text as new line this code is doing well, but I have multiple value in one row then it does not print that row, it only prints another row. How to solve this problem 
buffer is string.

```
buffer  =  [buffer stringByAppendingFormat: @"\r\n%@", rowString];
```

Answer (score 0):

"\n\n" should give you a new line.